# Watin element finder error

Tags: watin, ui-automation

I am getting the below error when I try and find an element. My find method below.

```
public Element FindMenuItem(string menuItemName)
{
    var menuItem = Element(Find.ByText(menuItemName));
    var cells = ((ElementContainer<Element>)(menuItem)).TableCells;
    return cells.Count > 0 ? cells.First() : menuItem;
}
```

The error:

> WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException: It's not possible to find the element because no element finder is available.

Comment: What version of Watin are you using and what browser/version?

Comment: I was using one versio before the current one and IE9, I've just got the latest and the error is gone yay :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with Watin, get the latest build and it should be fixed.  Link to bug below.

http://sourceforge.net/p/watin/bugs/176/